# Scanner will not wait for new input

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I have a program that works as expected except for one important aspect of it.

The program is supposed to deal out a random card from a standard deck every time the enter button is pressed.

As of now I can get the program to give me a random card when I press enter, but I can not get it to work one at a time. My console fills all 52 cards into it after pressing enter once.

How can I get it to wait each time for me to press enter before dealing the next card? (The card dealing function is the while loop near the end)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Card {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
              String[] suit = {" of Diamonds", " of Spades", " of Hearts", " of Clubs"}; //Array of suits
              String[] faces = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};//Array of face values
              String[] deck = new String[52];//Array of actual deck
              int[] random = new int[52]; //Array with all possible numbers between 1-52
              boolean deckComplete = false;//Boolean for finished deck

              for (int x = 0; x<random.length; x++) {
                      random[x] = x;
              } //Fills array with all possible numbers between 1-52

              Random rndNum = new Random();

              Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
              String readString = scanner.nextLine();

              for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
                      deck[i] = faces[i % 13] + suit[i/13];
              } //Creates array with all possible cards in standard deck of cards

              ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(deck)); //Converts above array into ArrayList


              while (deckComplete == false) {
                      for (int i = 52; i >= 1; i--) {
                              int randomNumber = rndNum.nextInt(i);
                              if (readString.equals("")) {
                                      System.out.println(arrayList.get(random[randomNumber]));
                                      arrayList.remove(random[randomNumber]);
                                      if (i == 1) {
                                              deckComplete = true;
                                      } //Deals out random card from deck and removes each one used
                              }
                      }

              }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is only doing what you tell it to do, no more and no less. Think through the code in your mind logically -- and you'll see that the `scanner.nextLine()` is only being called once, **before** the for loop, and so your program will thus wait for input **only once**, just as it is written. Instead, the line of code needs to be called **within** the for loop, if you want to wait for input before dealing each card. Again right now that line of code is only called once.

Comment: Ah, I knew it must've been a silly mistake. I'm still new to Java. Thank you!

Comment: @andrewxt: again the key is to always walk through your code mentally and to see what it's doing.